# How to change path names for media from localhost to some other local URL in Magento?

Tags: php, magento

I deployed Magento application on my local. When I am trying to access it using some other system in my local network, application gets opened but am not getting images and css. It is getting resolved to localhost/magento/imagename.jpg. My application is deployed in 127.0.0.1/magento/. Do I need to change my PHP.ini or some setting in Magento Admin?

Comment: Is everything working fine on your local machine? What is the behaviour when accessing from another machine within your network, I guess page loads, then the links are broken. I guess this is most likely a `.htaccess` problem, make sure you have it. I'd also have a play with the settings at `System -> Configuration -> (Choose website congiuration scope) -> Web`. Fail that configure apache to listen on your local network ip.

Comment: @input- When I change it to my local IP it refreshes and becomes local host again. I also tried to change frontName in local.xml to my local IP. But now my admin panel is not working.

Comment: You need to configure magento to link to your network ip in the web section, I think Ricks answer below should cover it, as a start use the optionally instructions to see if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the base url to your internal IP address, the ip address your router assigns to you.

In Windows:

Start -> Type in `cmd` and press enter -> `ipconfig`

In Linux:

`ifconfig`

Find your local IP which might look like 192.168.1.xx or 10.0.0.xx
Enter that as your Base URL (with http:// in front and / at the end) in the magento backend under System -> Configuration -> Web

**OPTIONALLY**

You can enter `{{base_url}}` as your Base URL in magento backend, this will allow any URL to work, this is however not recommended for live.

**EDIT**

Don't forget to clear your cache by deleting everything in `var/cache/`

Comment: I tried this. When I change it to my local IP it refreshes and becomes localhost again. I also tried to change frontName in local.xml to my local IP. But now my admin panel is not working.

Comment: leave your local.xml as it is, make sure you clear everything in `var/cache/` after changing your base url to your local ip.

Comment: I cleared my cache. Can you tell default value for frontName in local.xml?